# Getting list of friends using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to get a list of friends using facebook explorer

[https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/{access-token}/?method=GET&path={fb-id}%2Ffriends&version=v14.0](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/%7Baccess-token%7D/?method=GET&path=%7Bfb-id%7D%2Ffriends&version=v14.0)

access-token is auto generated (I'm using App Token) and {fb-id} is the Test User Accounts' id

This is what I got

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

Just FYI: I'm using the test users as well as real accounts, and I've requested user_friends for my app (but currently rejected as I haven't been verified as individual and I haven't submitted my app for review)

On the app permission, it says that I've used user_friends API 25 times (for the past 30 days) -- but the number doesn't increase anymore

I could have sworn it works yesterday using my application, but now, it doesn't even works on the facebook explorer

This is the output that I see

fbFriend Connection[afterCursor=null beforeCursor=null data=[] nextPageUrl=null order= previousPageUrl=null totalCount=4 next=false previous=false]

Do I use the facebook explorer correctly?
Does anyone have the same problem?

thanks

Edited:
[image: I've created test accounts with correct permission and invite/accept friend request from other test users]
I've created test accounts with correct permission and invite/accept friend request from other test users

Answer (score 0):

Per the [User Friends documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/friends):

> Only friends who have installed the app and who have granted the app the user_friends permission will be included.

Therefore, if no other user installed your application, you won't see them in the response. However, the `total_count` in `summary` object will reflect the actual number of user's friends.

Comment: thanks for the answer
I've edited my question, showing that the test accounts that I've created already friends with each other and have the correct user_friends permission